# Android json image parsing

Tags: java, php

how can i get the image in the android app form mysql database using json parsing.

i have following php code

```html
<?
 require('dbHelper.php');
 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM Image;";
 
 
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
 $response=array();
 while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  array_push($response,array("image"=>$row[1],"pname"=>$row[2],"productprice"=>$row[3],"producttype"=>$row[4],"productsale"=>$row[5]));
 }
 echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
 mysqli_close($con);
  
?>
```

This is the json:

```
{"server_response":[
   {"image":"","pname":"para","productprice":"555","producttype‌​":"M","productsale":"50"},
   {"image":"","pname":"streer","productprice":"500","prod‌​ucttype":"E","productsale":"5"},
   {"image":"","pname":"jire ko dhad","productprice":"90","producttype":"","productsale":"90"},
   {"image":"","pnam‌​e":"jire ko dhad","productprice":"90","producttype":"","productsale":"500"},
   {"image":"","pna‌me":"pah","productprice":"15000","producttype":"E","productsale":"50"}
]}
```

but the problem is , it parse the strings, but in the image field , there is no link. how can i overcome this

Comment: That depends on how you're storing the value in images table. What is being stored in `image` column ?

Comment: Is the value an URL?

Comment: {"server_response":[{"image":"","pname":"para","productprice":"555","producttype":"M","productsale":"50"},{"image":"","pname":"streer","productprice":"500","producttype":"E","productsale":"5"},{"image":"","pname":"jire ko dhad","productprice":"90","producttype":"","productsale":"90"},{"image":"","pname":"jire ko dhad","productprice":"90","producttype":"","productsale":"500"},{"image":"","pname":"pah","productprice":"15000","producttype":"E","productsale":"50"}]}
@Blobonat
**this is the response, but image field is empty**

Comment: first check if the desired data is returned from database by doing a `var_dump($row)` for example.

Comment: It shows 'NULL' @Jeff